# How to organise the entity model for play framework 2 when working with anorm

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, anorm

I have a table with a set of fields, and foreign keys.

When working with Ebean I can specify which fields to fill in a request, starting only with the id ending with external relations (not always need to have all the fields from the database in the class). It uses only one class tied to the table.

```
@Entity
public class Product extends Model{   

@Id
public Long id;

@Constraints.Required
public String name;

@Lob
public String description;

@ManyToOne
public Trademark trademark;

...

}
```

**Q1**. When working with Anorm encouraged to use `case class`, but I need to specify all the possible fields of the `case class` and fill them. And if I need an object only with fields `Id` and `Name`, or only ref object with `Id`? I have to describe another class?

```
case class ProductRef (id: Pk[Long] = NotAssigned)
case class Product (id: Pk[Long] = NotAssigned, name: String)
case class ProductWithTrademark (id: Pk[Long] = NotAssigned, name: String, trademark: Trademark)
...
case class Trademark (id: Pk[Long] = NotAssigned, name: String ="")
```

**Q2**. What to do if you can use this table as a foreign key in another table? Which `case class` to use?

```
case class Size(id: Pk[Long] = NotAssigned, name: String)
case class ProductSize(id: Pk[Long] = NotAssigned, product: ??? , size: Size)
```

**Q3**. Or it would be better always to fill all the fields with default values and use only one `case class`

```
case class Product(id: Pk[Long] = NotAssigned, name: String="", trademark: Trademark = Trademark())
case class Trademark(id: Pk[Long] = NotAssigned, name: String="")
case class Size(id: Pk[Long] = NotAssigned, name: String = "")
case class ProductSize(id: Pk[Long] = NotAssigned, product: Product = Product(), size: Size = Size())
```

**Q4**. or there is the right decision about which **I simply have no idea**?

Answer (score 2):

The usual practice when you have a couple of fields that can be null in your tables is to set them as Option in your case class. For example, instead of having:

```
case class Product (id: Pk[Long] = NotAssigned, name: String)
case class ProductWithTrademark (id: Pk[Long] = NotAssigned, name: String, trademark: Trademark)
```

You would have:

```
case class Product (id: Pk[Long] = NotAssigned, name: String, trademark: Option[Trademark])
```

And then set your product parser to check if the `Trademark` is there or not.

---

The **computer-database** sample that comes with Play describes that exact same case. In that example they used the following case classes to describe their models:

```
case class Company(id: Pk[Long] = NotAssigned, name: String)
case class Computer(id: Pk[Long] = NotAssigned, name: String, introduced: Option[Date], discontinued: Option[Date], companyId: Option[Long])
```

You can see that the foreign key is set as `Option`, as the a `Computer` model can (not have) a `Company` linked to it. 
The `Computer` parser is then described as follows:

```
val simple = {
    get[Pk[Long]]("computer.id") ~
    get[String]("computer.name") ~
    get[Option[Date]]("computer.introduced") ~
    get[Option[Date]]("computer.discontinued") ~
    get[Option[Long]]("computer.company_id") map {
      case id~name~introduced~discontinued~companyId => Computer(id, name, introduced, discontinued, companyId)
    }
}
```

Notice how when parsing the foreign key, `get[Option[Long]]` is used.
The company parser is defined in the same manner, and when wanting to get both `Computer` and `Company` (If the foreign key `company_id` is set), they used the following parser that returns a tuple `(Computer,Option[Company])`:

```
val withCompany = Computer.simple ~ (Company.simple ?) map {
    case computer~company => (computer,company)
}
```

Comment: Maybe I can't describe what I want. Of course `nullable` fields of database must be `optional` in application, but my question about using `case class` without filling **all** fields, when reading from database only **id+name** (for example, if part of code needs only them).

Comment: Ah I understand now, well either create new case classes or put all the fields as Option as described above.

Comment: What about using two solutions? Using `option` with default `None`?

Comment: Actually, the parsers as described above would automatically return None if the field is null. Now, nothing prevents you from setting them to null by default, for sometimes you would need to create a case class and do something with it, or simply before inserting the corresponding information into database. So, yes, you could do both at the same time.

Comment: Exactly. `null` in `case class` for default, and `Option` for database nullable values. If in database stored `null` parser put `None` in `case class` field

Comment: Actually I meant that for default you could also put None, but yeah, that's the idea.

Comment: `null` for `scala` is not good and i try using for default "empty values" (case class without parameters). For example `case class Product(... , photo: ProductPhoto = ProductPhoto())` and `case class ProductPhoto(... , product: Product = Product())` and got result... java.lang.StackOverflowError: null :-)

Comment: It is normal to have a StackOverflow here because you are clearly creating an infinite creation loop. Creating a Product automatically creates a ProductPhoto, creating a ProductPhoto automatically creates a Product. I don't understand why you don't want to use the Option solution.

Comment: I understood the reason `StackOverflow`. Why I don't want using `Option`? Because I'll need use `x.get` on every field every where. I would like to use `Option` only with nullable database fields. I'm new to `Scala` and can confuse the use of the basic principles.

Comment: Well, you can do that, put only the fields that are nullable as options. Note that you shouldn't put x.get as x can be None, instead use getOrElse with a default value that would be return if x is None.

Comment: I made a mistake in the above example (Product-ProductPhoto). In my application cannot be stored photo of the goods without the product itself, but product without a product photo may exist and in the first place it goes to the database, so `case class Product(... , photo: Option[ProductPhoto] = None)` and `case class ProductPhoto(... , product: Product = Product())` is working code.